Delete parent when child is deleted joint inheritance mapping strategy
Can anyone help with this issue. It's my first time using spring boot, I'm trying to implement inheritance using Joined inheritance strategy. I've created an entity called AuditTrackable which is a superclass and User which is a subclass. Its all working well but when I delete a user, the row is deleted from the user table but when I check in the audittrackable table, the corresponding row referenced by the user_id is still is still appearing. I've a lot of deleted users whose ids are still appearing in the parent table(audittrackable). I would want the delete operation on the user entity to cascade to the parent entity so that a user is completely deleted. Any assistance will greatly be appreciated.
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)

public class AuditTrackable {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;
  private String status;
  @Column(updatable=false)
  @CreationTimestamp
  private Instant createdOn;
  @ManyToOne(optional=true) 
  @JoinColumn(name="created_by",nullable = true,updatable = false)
  private AuditTrackable createdBy;
  @UpdateTimestamp
  private Instant lastUpdatedOn;
  @ManyToOne(optional=true) 
  @JoinColumn(name="last_updated_by",nullable = true)
  private AuditTrackable lastUpdatedBy;
}

@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "user_id")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor

public class User extends AuditTrackable implements UserDetails {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Column(unique = true,updatable = false,nullable = false)
  private String username;
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String password;
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String firstname;
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String lastname;
  private String middlename;
  // more fields...
}


